# Update column value in if clause

Tags: python, pandas

This loop is working correctly. Only problem is that if the set elements are more than 3 then I need to update the dupmark column with 1.

```
for i in df['name_of_college_school'] :
    for y in dhee_df['college_name'] :
        if len( cleanup(i) & cleanup(y)) > 3:
            df['dupmark'] = 1
```

In the above case, it is changing the dupmark column to 1 for all rows and not only those where the if condition is satisfied.

How to use update statement in if clause?

Comment: Sure it is, you change the whole column each time condition is met. Can you please show example data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following and it is working as expected...

```
df.loc[df['name_of_college_school'] == i, 'dupmark'] = 2
```